# Javascript/AJAX and PHP/MySQL query returning very slowly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have javascript that slides in a div, then sends an ajax call to php to run a mysql query, then fills in the div with the responce. the problem is it takes over 6 seconds to fill in the div with the responce, even if i'm returning 0 rows or 1 row or 50 rows...my code is below, any help would be appreciated!

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
var seenFav=0;
$("#fav_btn").click(function () {
    if (seenFav==0){
    document.getElementById("fav_content").innerHTML ='<div id="favLoadingItem" style="width:32px; height:32px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:234px;"><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="loading" title="loading" /></div>';
    document.getElementById("favSelector").innerHTML ='<div id="favLoadingGroups" style="width:32px; height:32px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:234px;"><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="loading" title="loading" /></div>';
    }
    $("#fav_slider").animate({
        right: $("#fav_slider").parent().width() / 2 - $("#fav_slider").width() / 2
    }, 400);
    $("#fadeTwo").fadeIn(800);
    if (seenFav==0){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("fav_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("favLoadingItem").style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "includes/queries/favorites.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("id=f");
    seenFav=1;
    loadFavGroups();

    }
});
});

    function loadFavGroups() {
var x;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("favSelector").innerHTML = x.responseText;
        document.getElementById("favLoadingGroups").style.display = 'none';
    }
};
x.open("POST", "includes/queries/favorites.php", true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
x.send("id=fg");
}
```

PHP CODE

```
    // START FAVORITES SLIDER INITIAL LOAD-->


    $favs = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE (user='".$email."' AND (favGroup LIKE '".$favGroup."')) GROUP BY partNo");
    // Table header.
    echo '<table><tr>';
    do {
    // Fetch and print all the records:
    $cols = 5;
    for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++)
        { 
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($favs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if($row && $i<=$cols)
                {
                    echo '<td  class="favHover">
                            <div style="float: left; height: 115px; width: 100px; padding-left: 13px; margin-top: 15px;">
                            <a href="../../product.php?id='.$row['partId'].'"><div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="'.$row['partNo'].'">
                                <div style="height: 65px; width: 100px; background-size: cover; background-image:url(../images/product/' . $row['partNo'] . '/' . $row['partNo'] . '.jpg)">
                                </div></a><a href="../../product.php?id='.$row['partId'].'">
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; height: 20px; width: 100px; text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">' . $row['partNo'] . '</div></div></a>
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; height: 25px; width: 100px; text-align:center; margin-top:5px;"><div class="favTasks" style="font-size: 12px; height: 25px; width: 100px;"><a href="/includes/queries/specSheet.php?id='.$row['partId'].'" target="_blank"><i style="margin-left:10px; color:#000;" title="Printable Spec Sheet" class="fa fa-print fa-lg"></i></a><i style="margin-left:40px; color:#C80000;" title="Delete Item" class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>';
                }
        }
        echo '</tr>';  
        }
        while ($row); echo '</table>'; // Close the table.



    //END FAVORITES SLIDER INITIAL LOAD-->
    }
    //START FAVORITES SLIDER GROUPS

    elseif( $_POST["id"] == "fg"){
    echo"<table width='174' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='favChoices'>
    <tr id='all' class='selectedRow' >
    <td style=\"height:50px; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:solid 1px #000; line-height:50px; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;\"width='174'><a onclick=\"viewFav('all');\" ><div style='width:174px; height:50px; text-align:center; line-height:50px;'>All</div></a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id='0' >
    <td style=\"height:50px; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:solid 2px #000; line-height:50px; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;\"width='174'><a onclick=\"viewFav('0');\" ><div style='width:174px; height:50px; text-align:center; line-height:50px;'>Unsorted</div></a></td>
   </tr>";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM favgroups WHERE user='".$email."' ORDER BY groupName ASC");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr id='".$row['id']."' ondrop='drop(event,".$row['id'].")' ondragover='allowDrop(event,".$row['id'].")' ondragleave='dragLeave(event,".$row['id'].")'>
  <td style=\"height:50px; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:solid 1px #000; line-height:50px; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px;\"width='174'><a onclick=\"viewFav('".$row['id']."');\" ><div style='width:174px; height:50px; text-align:center; line-height:50px;'>".$row['groupName']."</div></a></td>
  </tr>";
  }  
  echo"</table>";
  }
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Is it slow php action, SQL request or js? What is the timing of ajax request?
I would advise transfer just json data, NOT html formatted data - it will save traffic and optimize perfomance.

Comment: And as soon as you alreafy use jquery, use jquery ajax and render.

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools for a start. This should tell you whether it's waiting for the script to return (likely) or whether that's fast and the JS takes that long to write data to the DOM (unlikely).

Comment: It is waiting a long time for the script to return, but i do not know why, because if i run the script alone in the browser it is less than half a second return time, but when coupled with the js it is a 6second return time...

Comment: have you tried the $.ajax function??? You need to set the Content-Length header manually..